# Ajax replacment for JavaScript prompt command

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

The JavaScript prompt command

```
prompt("sometext","defaultvalue");
```

is a useful way to easily prompt the user to provide a value. But it can't really be a part of any polished web 2.0 application (The dialog looks horrible).

Is there any existing component to display a modal dialog that will prompt a user for a value? I can use a pure JavaScript solution or anything developed for ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are a lot of things that fit the bill in of the most javascript frameworks out there.  For instance, there are a few out there for jQuery e.g. [Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php) or if you want something specifically for ASP.NET then there are few things you could probably use from the [ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/)  such as the [Modal Dialog](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) or of course, you could roll your own!

Comment: Impromptu looks like what I need. Going to try it

Answer (score 0):

You can code your own solution with a `div` containing an input field and a button and some JavaScript to show/hide the `div`.

This will not block the JavaScript code flow so you will have to set a callback function on the `Close`/`Ok` button.

If you are ok with JS libraries almost all of them have a `Dialog` widget.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: I doubt that there is a way to write blocking code in JavaScript, so pure JavaScript solution is unlikely to be out there. Callbacks/EventHandlers seems to be the only choice.

Comment: By the way I found a language that compiles down to JavaScript and let you code async calls as you were doing things synchronously
http://ajaxian.com/archives/narrative-javascript-async-blocking-for-js